# Apple Signin Domain verification failed

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

[image]

I am trying to do the Sign-in with apple feature in my iOS app with support for iOS less than iOS 13, I got suggestions from the web to do it with Apple Sign in JS. In order to do that I need to create a Service for Authentication. I completed steps up to domain verification, as per mentioned in a [blog](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple). but can't verify the domain.

I am using a subdomain. I downloaded the file and uploaded in .well-known folder correctly as mentioned. Tried more times but no result. Do I miss anything? Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: what was the domain that you added , give me the format of it

Comment: You may need to wait a few minutes because of the cache. You can see if this is the problem by right-clicking on the page: Inspect>Network>Disable Cache on Chrome.

Comment: Are you able to upload to the apex domain, or just the subdomain? Have you checked you can access the file from the web? i.e. https://subdomain.yourdomain.tld/.well-known/apple-developer-domain-association.txt? If you can't visit the file from the web, then neither can Apple.

Comment: Yes, File is accessible on the web. I uploaded it to a subdomain and it is accessible in the web can see the textfile right in the browser.

Comment: I have waited and tried same 2, 3 time still seen as not verified!

Answer (score 0):

1. check your domain has redirect logic or not, for example, if your site redirects `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, then verification probably will fail. It was mentioned in Apple's document. You might need to remove the redirect logic temporary then click that verify button.
2. looks like apple can only verify the top domain, I don't think `www.example.com` will work, but `example.com` should work.